# C - DrMemory Leak Report Output, help to understand

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I got a question about the Dr Memory Report Output, helping to understand it.
I use Windows 10 64Bit and my Application is a 32 Bit Application.
Its builded with Mingw32.
Its a Snake Game. I used the C-Binding of the SFML API.
I enabled at compiling -wall and -wextra. I got no warnings.

The Report is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/474lcto4alp5i10/Desktop.txt?dl=0

I just running for interest it with Dr. Memory. I got actual no explicit Memory problem. My own allocations are all free'ed at the end.
I could figure out the "uninitialized accesses" are maybe false positives, because of the this error:
"Running on an unsupported operating system. Please download http://drmemory.org/syscalls_wow64.txt and save as C:\Program Files (x86)\Dr. Memory\bin\syscalls_wow64.txt to avoid false positives and other problems. If that fails, please file a bug report." (I followed these steps, but this isnt working).

And on the other side i figured out, that the possible leaks are also may false positives.

But my report also says i have LEAKS.
"     14 unique,   225 total,  37636 byte(s) of leak(s)"

Some of this unique is this here:

```
    Error #163: LEAK 96 direct bytes 0x05311618-0x05311678 + 0 indirect bytes
    # 0 replace_RtlAllocateHeap               [d:\drmemory_package\common\alloc_replace.c:3770]
    # 1 AcLayers.dll!?                       +0x0      (0x67e503c2 <AcLayers.dll+0x203c2>)
    # 2 csfml-graphics-2.dll!sfView_zoom     +0xaf14e  (0x71b7992f <csfml-graphics-2.dll+0xb992f>)
    # 3 csfml-graphics-2.dll!sfView_zoom     +0x9971f  (0x71b63f00 <csfml-graphics-2.dll+0xa3f00>)
    # 4 csfml-graphics-2.dll!sfView_zoom     +0x28523  (0x71af2d04 <csfml-graphics-2.dll+0x32d04>)
    # 5 csfml-graphics-2.dll!sfView_zoom     +0x32cca  (0x71afd4ab <csfml-graphics-2.dll+0x3d4ab>)
    # 6 csfml-graphics-2.dll!sfView_zoom     +0x2f555  (0x71af9d36 <csfml-graphics-2.dll+0x39d36>)
    # 7 csfml-graphics-2.dll!sfView_zoom     +0x2d0c5  (0x71af78a6 <csfml-graphics-2.dll+0x378a6>)
    # 8 csfml-graphics-2.dll!sfView_zoom     +0x9a220  (0x71b64a01 <csfml-graphics-2.dll+0xa4a01>)
    # 9 csfml-graphics-2.dll!sfView_zoom     +0x2d2c5  (0x71af7aa6 <csfml-graphics-2.dll+0x37aa6>)
    #10 csfml-graphics-2.dll!sfView_zoom     +0x2812f  (0x71af2910 <csfml-graphics-2.dll+0x32910>)
    #11 csfml-graphics-2.dll!sfView_zoom     +0x2d8fd  (0x71af80de <csfml-graphics-2.dll+0x380de>)
...
Error #159: LEAK 7656 direct bytes 0x0530b908-0x0530d6f0 + 208 indirect bytes
# 0 replace_RtlAllocateHeap               [d:\drmemory_package\common\alloc_replace.c:3770]
# 1 AcLayers.dll!?                       +0x0      (0x67e503c2 <AcLayers.dll+0x203c2>)
# 2 csfml-graphics-2.dll!sfView_zoom     +0xaf14e  (0x71b7992f <csfml-graphics-2.dll+0xb992f>)
# 3 csfml-graphics-2.dll!sfView_zoom     +0x9971f  (0x71b63f00 <csfml-graphics-2.dll+0xa3f00>)
# 4 csfml-graphics-2.dll!sfView_zoom     +0x26edb  (0x71af16bc <csfml-graphics-2.dll+0x316bc>)
# 5 csfml-graphics-2.dll!sfView_zoom     +0x26dfc  (0x71af15dd <csfml-graphics-2.dll+0x315dd>)
# 6 csfml-graphics-2.dll!sfView_zoom     +0x27d35  (0x71af2516 <csfml-graphics-2.dll+0x32516>)
# 7 csfml-graphics-2.dll!sfView_zoom     +0x27a02  (0x71af21e3 <csfml-graphics-2.dll+0x321e3>)
# 8 csfml-graphics-2.dll!sfView_zoom     +0x26287  (0x71af0a68 <csfml-graphics-2.dll+0x30a68>)
# 9 csfml-graphics-2.dll!sfView_zoom     +0xcace   (0x71ad72af <csfml-graphics-2.dll+0x172af>)
#10 csfml-graphics-2.dll!sfRenderWindow_create+0xbb     (0x71ac572c <csfml-graphics-2.dll+0x572c>)
#11 CSFMLInit                             [C:/Users/Master of Penetrator/Desktop/SnakeGame/SnakeGame/CSFMLMenu.c:7]
...
```

My Question is now, how i can interpret these Errors?

Is the tool telling me, there is a problem with the intern DLL Functions here? Or still in my Application?

For exmaple: In my application i use the sfView(for camera), but i never call the sfView_zoom subfunction.

Maybe you can give me some tips, how to interpret these errors.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `-w` disables warnings. To enable warnings, you need `-W`.

Comment: Iam sorry, it was just a missspelling here. I meant -Wall and -Wextra. In Codeblocks these are just "Checkboxes" to activate it.

Comment: I could find out, thats maybe the graphics drive is responsible for that